# Split function is skipping results VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, split

So i'm trying to read a text file and split the data using a character array of "!!!"
I'm having a lot of trouble working with it, as it is for some reason skipping by 3s.
so in the array, md(), I am getting the proper string for md(0), but md(1) and md(2) have no content. md(3) is however the 2nd argument in the split, and md(6) is the 3rd argument in the split.
[Screenshot of the results and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeWh2.png)

This is the whole sub that is being called:

```
  Public Sub recompile()
    Try
        ' Open the file using a stream reader.
        Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\Connor\Documents\MovieTheaterPro\MovieData.txt")
            Dim line As String
            Dim inThisRow As Integer = 0
            Dim rows As Integer = 0
            Dim lineCount = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Connor\Documents\MovieTheaterPro\MovieData.txt").Length
            For i As Integer = 0 To lineCount - 1 Step 1
                line = sr.ReadLine()
                MsgBox(line)
                Dim md As String() = line.Split("!!!")
                Dim addTo As String = ""
                For i2 As Integer = 0 To md.Length - 1 Step 1
                    addTo += "md(" & i2 & "): " & md(i2) & vbNewLine
                Next
                MsgBox(addTo)
                If inThisRow = 6 Then
                    rows += 1
                    inThisRow = 0
                End If
                Dim pb As New PictureBox
                pb.Width = 170
                pb.Height = 200
                pb.Top = 172 + (rows * 213)
                pb.Left = 12 + (227 * inThisRow)
                pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
                If (md.Length > 0) Then
                    pb.Image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(New IO.MemoryStream(New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(md(1))))
                End If
                Me.Controls.Add(pb)
                inThisRow += 1
            Next



        End Using
    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:")
        Console.WriteLine(e)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: That Split() call just doesn't work the way you think it does.  You'll want to practice coding for a while with Option Strict On at the top of the source code file, now the compiler tells you what you are doing wrong.   Do use the TextFieldParser class instead.  Practicing using the debugger is going to pay off handsomely as well, those MsgBox calls are just painful to wrestle through.

Comment: You need to use a different overload of [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx), thus `Dim md As String() = input.Split({"!!!"}, StringSplitOptions.None)`.

Comment: Also, you are reading your file twice, unnecessarily.  Get rid of the outer `For` loop and use a `While` loop instead with your `StreamReader`.  Use `line = sr.ReadLine()  While line IsNot Nothing 'Rest of your code here End While`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.Split` has different behaviour when the split string has more than one character. You can use `Strings.Split` instead (VB only).

```
Dim md As String() = Strings.Split(line,"!!!")
```

You can see the difference between this two function as below

```
Sub Main()
        Dim input = "a!!!b!!!c!!!d"
        Dim first() = input.Split("!!!")
        Dim second() = Strings.Split(input, "!!!")

        Console.WriteLine(Join(first, "-"))
        Console.WriteLine(Join(second, "-"))
        Console.Read()
End Sub
```

Output

> a---b---c---d
>
> a-b-c-d

Overall, It could be better if you use regex for this type string parsing operations.